# imageView.animate() in loop does not work

Tags: java, android

so i have to move an image around square in 4 cases i have to decide to move up,right,left or down

i am trying with imageView.animate() in for loop but it is not working correctly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
int x = image.getX();
int y = image.geyY();
if(1 case)
image.animate().x(x - 10).y(y);
else if(2 case)
image.animate().x(x + 10).y(y);
else if(3 case)
image.animate().x(x).y(y - 10);
else
image.animate().x(x).y(y + 10);

 image.invalidate();
}
```

image animate only once instead of three times
i can do it by:
for example: in 1 case

```
image.animate().x(x - 30).y(y);
```

but i have to check cases after one move (one move it is +- 10px)
any idea?